# How can I make an arrow from a point in one axis to a point in another?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have created this bit of code, which is the beginning of an illustration of how a neighborhood around a point in a manifold maps to a region in the plane:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    name=mfd,
                    declare function={
                            f(\x,\y)=10-(\x^2+\y^2);
                    },
                    declare function={
                            c_x(\t)=(cos(\t)+(sin(5*\t)/10))/3+1;
                    },
                    declare function={
                            c_y(\t)=(sin(\t))/2-1;
                    },
                    declare function={
                            c_z(\t)=f(c_x(\t),c_y(\t));
                    },
            ]
                    \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2,]{f(x,y)};
                    \addplot3[black,opacity=1.0,variable=t,domain=0:360,dashed,thin] ({c_x(t)},{c_y(t)},{c_z(t)});
                    \addplot3[black,opacity=1.0,only marks,mark=text,text mark=$\cdot$] (1,-1,{f(1,-1)});
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[
                    at={($(mfd.north east)+(1cm,-5cm)$)},
                    anchor=north west,
                    declare function={
                            c_x(\t)=(cos(\t)+(sin(5*\t)/10))/3+1;
                    },
                    declare function={
                            c_y(\t)=(sin(\t))/2-1;
                    }
            ]
                    \addplot[variable=t,domain=0:360]({c_x(t)},{c_y(t)});
                    \addplot[black,opacity=1.0,only marks,mark=text,text mark=$\cdot$] (1,-1);
            \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, I'm struggling to find the best way to make an arrow from the dot in the middle of the (topological) circle on the 3D surface to the corresponding point int the plane, since they are in separate axis environments. Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a `coordinate` at the end of each of the plots, and then draw a normal arrow after the second `axis`.
[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.12}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                    name=mfd,
                    declare function={
                            f(\x,\y)=10-(\x^2+\y^2);
                    },
                    declare function={
                            c_x(\t)=(cos(\t)+(sin(5*\t)/10))/3+1;
                    },
                    declare function={
                            c_y(\t)=(sin(\t))/2-1;
                    },
                    declare function={
                            c_z(\t)=f(c_x(\t),c_y(\t));
                    },
            ]
                    \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2,]{f(x,y)};
                    \addplot3[black,opacity=1.0,variable=t,domain=0:360,dashed,thin] ({c_x(t)},{c_y(t)},{c_z(t)});
                    \addplot3[black,opacity=1.0,only marks,mark=text,text mark=$\cdot$] (1,-1,{f(1,-1)}) coordinate (a);
            \end{axis}
            \begin{axis}[
                    at={($(mfd.north east)+(1cm,-5cm)$)},
                    anchor=north west,
                    declare function={
                            c_x(\t)=(cos(\t)+(sin(5*\t)/10))/3+1;
                    },
                    declare function={
                            c_y(\t)=(sin(\t))/2-1;
                    }
            ]
                    \addplot[variable=t,domain=0:360]({c_x(t)},{c_y(t)});
                    \addplot[black,opacity=1.0,only marks,mark=text,text mark=$\cdot$] (1,-1) coordinate (b);
            \end{axis}

\draw [-stealth,shorten <=3pt,shorten >=3pt] (a) to[bend left] (b);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```