# A useful illustration for differential geometry

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-styles

I'm working on creating an illustration that I will need in many, different guises in differential geometry/manifold theory etc. Following on from a previous (answered) question of mine ([How can I make an arrow from a point in one axis to a point in another?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388190/how-can-i-make-an-arrow-from-a-point-in-one-axis-to-a-point-in-another/), I want to show how two coordinate lines in the plane originate from two curves on a surface via the chosen map:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            name=mfd,
            declare function={
                    f(\x,\y)=10-(\x^2+\y^2);
            },      
            declare function={
                    c_x(\t)=(cos(\t)+(sin(5*\t)/10))/3+1;
            },      
            declare function={
                    c_y(\t)=(sin(\t))/2-1;
            },      
            declare function={
                    c_z(\t)=f(c_x(\t),c_y(\t));
            },      
    ]       
            \addplot3[surf,domain=-2:2,domain y=-2:2,]{f(x,y)};
            \addplot3[black,opacity=1.0,variable=t,domain=0:360,dashed,thin] ({c_x(t)},{c_y(t)},{c_z(t)});
            \addplot3[black,opacity=1.0,variable=t,domain=-2:2,thin] (t,-1.2,{f(t,-1.2)});
            \addplot3[black,opacity=1.0,variable=t,domain=-2:2,thin] (0.8,t,{f(t,-1.2)});
            \addplot3[black,opacity=1.0,only marks,mark=text,text mark=$\cdot$] (1,-1,{f(1,-1)}) coordinate (a);
    \end{axis}
    \begin{axis}[
            at={($(mfd.north east)+(1cm,-2cm)$)},
            anchor=north west,
            declare function={
                    c_x(\t)=(cos(\t)+(sin(5*\t)/10))/3+1;
            },      
            declare function={
                    c_y(\t)=(sin(\t))/2-1;
            }       
    ]       
            \addplot[variable=t,domain=0:360]({c_x(t)},{c_y(t)});
            \addplot[black,opacity=1.0,only marks,mark=text,text mark=$\cdot$] (1,-1) coordinate (b);
            \addplot[variable=t,domain=0.6:1.4](t,-1.2);
            \addplot[variable=t,domain=-1.5:-0.5](0.8,t);
    \end{axis}
    \draw [-stealth, shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt] (a) to[bend left] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

However, I have a couple of problems:

- The curves representing the coordinate axes pulled back from the plane via the coordinate map insist on being closed off with a straight line - is there a way to avoid that?
- I want to draw all the black curves with a thin, dashed line, but I probably don't understand how to set those options. What am I doing wrong?

I apologise if these questions are rather elementary, but I find the relevant manuals difficult to search through; they seem to be meant for reading cover to cover rather than reference.

Comment: `thin,dashed` makes it what you'd think. Use `very thin` or `ultra thin` to get it thinner.

Comment: Setting the line width to 0pt is actually 1 pixel wide (whatever 1 pixel is on the display device).

Comment: well, it doesn't seem to work in this case:

Comment: oops, ran into a silly time limit before I had finished my comment: well, it doesn't seem to work in this case: "\addplot3[black,opacity=1.0,variable=t,domain=0:360,dashed,thin] ({c_x(t)},{c_y(t)},{c_z(t)});" (from my code snippet above)

Comment: Hm, yes, I see that now, sorry.  Odd. (By the way, I'd forgotten that `thin` is actually the default line width, so use e.g. `very thin` to make it thinner than default.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for the problem, I think, can be found in this quote from the `pgfplots` manual:

> If there is no value for neither `mesh/rows` nor `mesh/cols` or if one of them is 1, `pgfplots` will draw a
>   line plot. [...]
>
> For `\addplot3 expression`, **this requires to set `samples y=0` to disable the generation of a mesh**.

(Emphasis mine.) Note that `samples y=1` will also work, and the manual says this at another point:

> If you use `\addplot3 expression`, `mesh/rows` and `mesh/cols` are computed from the values `samples` and `samples y`. By default, `\addplot3 expression` always samples a mesh. **If you want it to sample a line, set `samples y=1`** (or, equivalently, `y domain=0:0`).

(Again, emphasis mine. I don't know the technical differences between the two.)

Seems line specifications didn't work for a mesh, and the mesh is also the reason you got closed curves. Hence, if you set `samples y=0` for your black lines, it works as expected.  I did that via a style, in the example below.

I actually made three different styles, one for the point, one for the coordinate lines, one for the shape, one for the point. You also had the wrong z-coordinate for the second coordinate line, it should be `f(0.8,t)` not `f(t,-1.2)`.

For the annotations, you can use relative coordinates. Say you have a saved coordinate `c`, you can do something like

```
\draw [stealth-] (c) to[bend left] ++(2cm,1cm) node[right] {...};
```

This puts the arrow tip at the start of the path, and the node at the end is placed at `right` of the end of the path. This saves you absolute coordinates, and also having to reuse those in the `\node`.

I also modified some of the math, notably use `\dim` instead of `dim`, and e.g. `$...$ for $...$` instead of `$... \ for\ ...$`.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{diagrams}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
  myarrow/.style={stealth-,shorten >=3pt,shorten <=3pt}
}
\pgfplotsset{
  lineplot/.style={
    black,
    dashed,
    very thin,
    samples y=0
  },
  coordinate line/.style={
    black,
    samples y=0
  },
  point/.style={
    only marks,
    mark=*,
    black,
    mark size=0.5pt
  }
}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]


\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        Let $\mathbf{M}$ be a smooth manifold and $p \in \mathbf{M}$; then $\dim(\mathbf{T_pM}) = dim(\mathbf{M})$
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}
        To prove this, we construct a vector space basis for $\mathbf{T_pM}$ from a chart. Choose a chart $(U,x), with \  p \in U$. Consider $\dim(\mathbf{M})$ curves $\gamma_{(a)}$, with   $a = 1, \dots, \dim(\mathbf{M}), \gamma_{(a)} \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow U$, so that $(x^b \circ \gamma_{(a)}) (\lambda) = \delta^b_a \cdot \lambda$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ -- like this:

        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                name=mfd,
                axis lines=none,
                declare function={
                    f(\x,\y)=10-(\x^2+\y^2);
                },
                declare function={
                    c_x(\t)=(cos(\t)+(sin(5*\t)/10))/3+1;
                },
                declare function={
                    c_y(\t)=(sin(\t))/2-1;
                },
                declare function={
                    c_z(\t)=f(c_x(\t),c_y(\t));
                },
                declare function={
                    x_0(\t)=-1.2;
                },
                declare function={
                    x_1(\t)=0.8;
                }
            ]
                \addplot3[surf,domain=0:2,domain y=-2:0,]{f(x,y)};
                \addplot3[lineplot,variable=t,domain=0:360] ({c_x(t)},{c_y(t)},{c_z(t)});
                \addplot3[coordinate line,variable=t,domain=0:2] (t,{x_0(t)},{f(t,{x_0(t)})});
                \addplot3[coordinate line,variable=t,domain=-2:0] ({x_1(t)},t,{f({x_1(t)},t)});
                \addplot3[point] (1,-1,{f(1,-1)}) coordinate (a);
                \addplot3[point](.5,{x_0(.5)},{f(.5,{x_0(.5)})}) coordinate (x_dot);
                \addplot3[point]({x_1(-.5)},-.5,{f({x_1(-.5)},-.5)}) coordinate (y_dot);
            \end{axis}
            \draw [myarrow]  (x_dot) to[bend left] ++(-2cm,-4cm) node[below] {$\gamma_{(0)}$};
            \draw [myarrow]  (y_dot) to[bend right] ++(2cm,0.5cm) node [right] {$\gamma_{(1)}$};
            \begin{axis}[
                at={($(mfd.north east)+(1cm,-2cm)$)},
                anchor=north west,
                axis lines=none,
                declare function={
                    c_x(\t)=(cos(\t)+(sin(5*\t)/10))/3+1;
                },
                declare function={
                    c_y(\t)=(sin(\t))/2-1;
                },
                declare function={
                    x_0(\t)=-1.2;
                },
                declare function={
                    x_1(\t)=0.8;
                }
            ]
                \addplot[lineplot,variable=t,domain=0:360]({c_x(t)},{c_y(t)});
                \addplot[point] (1,-1) coordinate (b);
                \addplot[coordinate line,variable=t,domain=0.6:1.4](t,{x_0(t)});
                \addplot[coordinate line,variable=t,domain=-1.5:-0.5]({x_1(t)},t);
                \addplot[point](.8,-.5) coordinate (P1);
                \addplot[point](.6,-1.2) coordinate (P2);
            \end{axis}
            \draw [myarrow] (b) to[bend right] node [above=7pt] {$x$} (a);
            \draw [myarrow] (P1) to[bend left] ++(-1cm,1cm) node[above] {$(x \circ \gamma_{(1)})$};
            \draw [myarrow] (P2) to[bend left] ++(-3cm,-1cm) node[above] {$(x \circ \gamma_{(0)})$};
        \end{tikzpicture}

        Given $p \in \mathbf{M}$, choose a chart $(U,x)$, so that $x(p)=0_{\mathbb{R}^{\dim M}}$, and curves $\gamma_{(a)}$, with $p = \gamma_{(a)}(0)$, for $a = 1, \dots, \dim M$:
        \begin{align*}
            e_a &:= X_{\gamma_{(a)},p}, a = 1, \dots, \dim M \\
            e_a f &= X_{\gamma_{(a)},p} f \\
            &=(f \circ \gamma_{(a)})' (0) \\
            &= (f \circ x^{-1} \circ x \circ \gamma_{(a)})' (0) \\
            &= \partial_b (f \circ x^{-1}) \cdot (x(\gamma_{(a)}(0))) \cdot (x^b \circ \gamma_{(a)})' (0) \\
            &= \partial_b (f \circ x^{-1})(x(p)) \cdot \delta^b_a \\
            &= \partial_a (f \circ x^{-1})
        \end{align*}
        (to be continued ...)
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's great - I had, finally, stumbled over the 'samples y=0' to get rid of the unwanted closure of the coordinate curves, but I hadn't got as far as the styles. I will massage it a bit more and publish the result as an answer below - it might be of interest to others.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n I updated my answer, so show a slightly different way of making those annotation arrows, using relative coordinates as opposed to explicit ones.

Comment: Torbjørn - we're not supposed to say "thanks", but thanks. Your edits make a lot of sense. Great stuff.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n You're welcome. (Personally, I think the whole "don't say thanks"-thing is a bit silly.)

Answer (score 1):

As promised, here is a bit of context for this illustration - it is part of a proof, so I have included some of the fluff around the picture:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{diagrams}
\usepackage[document]{ragged2e}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{tensor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\pgfplotsset{
  lineplot/.style={
    black,
    dashed,
    very thin,
    samples y=0
  },
  coordinate line/.style={
    black,
    samples y=0
  },
  point/.style={
    only marks,
    mark=*,
    black,
    mark size=0.5pt
  }
}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]

\begin{document}
    \begin{theorem}
        Let $\mathbf{M}$ be a smooth manifold and $p \in \mathbf{M}$; then $dim(\mathbf{T_pM}) = dim(\mathbf{M})$
    \end{theorem}
    \begin{proof}
        To prove this, we construct a vector space basis for $\mathbf{T_pM}$ from a chart. Choose a chart $(U,x), with \  p \in U$. Consider $dim(\mathbf{M})$ curves $\gamma_{(a)}, with \  a = 1, \dots, dim(\mathbf{M}), \gamma_{(a)} \colon \mathbb{R} \rightarrow U$, so that $(x^b \circ \gamma_{(a)}) (\lambda) = \delta^b_a \cdot \lambda$ for some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ - like this:\linebreak
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \begin{axis}[
                name=mfd,
                axis lines=none,
                declare function={
                    f(\x,\y)=10-(\x^2+\y^2);
                },
                declare function={
                    c_x(\t)=(cos(\t)+(sin(5*\t)/10))/3+1;
                },
                declare function={
                    c_y(\t)=(sin(\t))/2-1;
                },
                declare function={
                    c_z(\t)=f(c_x(\t),c_y(\t));
                },
                declare function={
                    x_0(\t)=-1.2;
                },
                declare function={
                    x_1(\t)=0.8;
                }
            ]
                \addplot3[surf,domain=0:2,domain y=-2:0,]{f(x,y)};
                \addplot3[lineplot,variable=t,domain=0:360] ({c_x(t)},{c_y(t)},{c_z(t)});
                \addplot3[coordinate line,variable=t,domain=0:2] (t,{x_0(t)},{f(t,{x_0(t)})});
                \addplot3[coordinate line,variable=t,domain=-2:0] ({x_1(t)},t,{f({x_1(t)},t)});
                \addplot3[point] (1,-1,{f(1,-1)}) coordinate (a);
                \addplot3[point](.5,{x_0(.5)},{f(.5,{x_0(.5)})}) coordinate (x_dot);
                \addplot3[point]({x_1(-.5)},-.5,{f({x_1(-.5)},-.5)}) coordinate (y_dot);
            \end{axis}
            \draw [-stealth, shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt] (.5,-.5) to[bend right] (x_dot);
            \node[below] at (.5,-.5) {$\gamma_{(0)}$};
            \draw [-stealth, shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt] (5,5) to[bend left] (y_dot);
            \node[right] at (5,5) {$\gamma_{(1)}$};
            \begin{axis}[
                at={($(mfd.north east)+(1cm,-2cm)$)},
                anchor=north west,
                axis lines=none,
                declare function={
                    c_x(\t)=(cos(\t)+(sin(5*\t)/10))/3+1;
                },
                declare function={
                    c_y(\t)=(sin(\t))/2-1;
                },
                declare function={
                    x_0(\t)=-1.2;
                },
                declare function={
                    x_1(\t)=0.8;
                }
            ]
                \addplot[lineplot,variable=t,domain=0:360]({c_x(t)},{c_y(t)});
                \addplot[black,opacity=1.0,only marks,mark=text,text mark=$\cdot$] (1,-1) coordinate (b);
                \addplot[coordinate line,variable=t,domain=0.6:1.4](t,{x_0(t)});
                \addplot[coordinate line,variable=t,domain=-1.5:-0.5]({x_1(t)},t);
                \addplot[point](.8,-.5) coordinate (P1);
                \addplot[point](.6,-1.2) coordinate (P2);
            \end{axis}
            \draw [-stealth, shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt] (a) to[bend left] node [above=7pt] {$x$} (b);
            \draw [-stealth, shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt] (9,4) to[bend right] (P1);
            \node[above] at (9,4) {$(x \circ \gamma_{(1)})$};
            \draw [-stealth, shorten <= 3pt, shorten >= 3pt] (5,-1) to[bend right] (P2);
            \node[above] at (5,-1) {$(x \circ \gamma_{(0)})$};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        Given $p \in \mathbf{M}$, choose a chart $(U,x)$, so that $x(p)=0_{\mathbb{R}^{dim M}}$, and curves $\gamma_{(a)}, with \  p = \gamma_{(a)}(0), for \ a = 1, \dots, dim M$:
        \begin{align*}
            e_a &:= X_{\gamma_{(a)},p}, a = 1, \dots, dim M \\
            e_a f &= X_{\gamma_{(a)},p} f \\
            &=(f \circ \gamma_{(a)})' (0) \\
            &= (f \circ x^{-1} \circ x \circ \gamma_{(a)})' (0) \\
            &= \partial_b (f \circ x^{-1}) \cdot (x(\gamma_{(a)}(0))) \cdot (x^b \circ \gamma_{(a)})' (0) \\
            &= \partial_b (f \circ x^{-1})(x(p)) \cdot \delta^b_a \\
            &= \partial_a (f \circ x^{-1})
        \end{align*}
        (to be continued ...)
    \end{proof}
\end{document}
```

There are still some loose ends - I'm not quite happy about the way I have had to use explicit coordinates for the arrows and their labels; it doesn't seem elegant, and there must be a better way. Also, there are visible blobs on the coordinate curves because of the way I placed a point there to have an end point for my arrows. Still, I hope it is useful for people.