# How to draw open curves in pgfplot?

Tags: pgfplots

I am currently working on the sketch below using pfgplots.
[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    hide axis,
    scale=2,
    view={120}{40},
    xmin=-4,xmax=4,
    ymin=-4,ymax=4,
    zmin=-2,zmax=10,
    trig format plots=rad,
  ]
  \addplot3 [ surf, colormap/bone, domain=-4:4, domain y=-4:4,
              samples=30, samples y=30,
              variable=\u, variable y=\v,
              point meta=u*v]
            ( {u}, {v}, {cos(u) + cos(v)} );

  \addplot3[black, dashed, thick, variable=\t, domain=-1:1] ( {1}, {t}, {cos(1) + cos(t) - 2});
  \addplot3[black, dashed, thick, variable=\t, domain=-1:1] ( {-1}, {t}, {cos(1) + cos(t) - 2});
  \addplot3[black, dashed, thick, variable=\t, domain=-1:1] ( {t}, {1}, {cos(1) + cos(t) - 2});
  \addplot3[black, dashed, thick, variable=\t, domain=-1:1] ( {t}, {-1}, {cos(1) + cos(t) - 2});

  \addplot3 [ surf, domain=-1:1, domain y=-1:1,
              samples=30, samples y=30,
              variable=\u, variable y=\v,
              point meta=u*v]
            ( {u}, {v}, {cos(u) + cos(v)} );

  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=-1:1] ( 1, t, {cos(1) + cos(t) + 2});
  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=-1:1] ( -1, {t}, {cos(1) + cos(t) + 2});
  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=-1:1] ( {t}, 1, {cos(1) + cos(t) + 2});
  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=-1:1] ( {t}, -1, {cos(1) + cos(t) + 2});

  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=-1:1] ( 1, {t}, {cos(1) + cos(t)});
  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=-1:1] ( -1, {t}, {cos(1) + cos(t)});
  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=-1:1] ( {t}, 1, {cos(1) + cos(t)});
  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=-1:1] ( {t}, -1, {cos(1) + cos(t)});

  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=0:2] ( 1, 1, {2*cos(1) + t});             
  \addplot3[black, thick, dashed, variable=\t, domain=0:2] ( 1, 1, {2*cos(1) - t});

  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=0:2] ( 1, -1, {2*cos(1) + t});             
  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=0:2] ( 1, -1, {2*cos(1) - t});

  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=0:2] ( -1, 1, {2*cos(1) + t});             
  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=0:2] ( -1, 1, {2*cos(1) - t});

  \addplot3[black, thick, variable=\t, domain=0:2] ( -1, -1, {2*cos(1) + t});             

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The black lines should represent a "box" that goes across the surface. The problem is that when I draw these black curves with \addplot3 I would like to get the "arch" only, but it draws a line between the endpoints as well so I end up with all these straight lines in my plot. In addition, it does not draw dashed curves. As to draw the blue surface I took an example from another post, I tried playing with the options of the axis to see which of them were necessary and if they fixed my problem, but I didn't succeed.

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Try adding `samples y=0` to the plots making those lines.

Comment: Same problem as https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388996/a-useful-illustration-for-differential-geometry/389211#389211 I believe, and `samples y=0` (or `samples y=1`) helps here as well, so I'm going to close as duplicate. Let me know if you disagree with that, and I can reopen.